# How to make if statement result do nothing?

Tags: java, android-mediaplayer

I want to ignore the result for if statement like ( pass in python )
Example

```
if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            // Do nothin
        } else {
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
```

Comment: And what's wrong with that, exactly?

Comment: I need the code replacing // Do nothin

Comment: You don't actually need to put anything there in that case.

Answer (score 3):

do it this way, just add a NOT(!) operator to if satement

```
if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Comment: BTW Your IDE should be able to re-arrange this code for you to give this answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 holder.more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (post.getPublisher().endsWith(firebaseUser.getUid())){

                //  ***----I want this to do nothing----***

            }else {

                //  ***--- The dialog should be displayed---***

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getRootView().getContext());
                View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(v.getRootView().getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_report_user,null);
                builder.setView(dialogView);
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.show();

                // ***----Although it will work you will get a warning and this is a wrong way----***
            }
        }
    });

    //*** ----instead do it like this code below---- JUST ADD AN !

    holder.more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!post.getPublisher().endsWith(firebaseUser.getUid())){ // On this line hope you noticed the change.

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getRootView().getContext());
                View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(v.getRootView().getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_report_user,null);
                builder.setView(dialogView);
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.show();
                
                //**** ----This is the right way----****

            }

        }
    });
```